# unable to generate Voronoi diagram from geospatial data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, voronoi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>D3.js GoogleMap Voronoi Diagram</title>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script       src="http://shimz.me/example/d3js/geo_example/geo_template/topojson.v0.min.js">         </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  sensor=false"></script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body, #map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.SvgOverlay {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;           
}

.SvgOverlay svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: -4000px;
    left: -4000px;
    width: 8000px;
    height: 8000px;        
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">

d3.json('bus-stops.json', function(pointjson){
    main(pointjson); 
});

function main(pointjson) {

    //Google Map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.290270,103.851959),       
    });


    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView(); //OverLay


    overlay.onAdd = function () {

        var layer =   d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div").attr("class",  "SvgOverlay");
        var svg = layer.append("svg");
        var svgoverlay = svg.append("g").attr("class", "AdminDivisions");


        overlay.draw = function () {
            var markerOverlay = this;
            var overlayProjection = markerOverlay.getProjection();

            //Google Map
            var googleMapProjection = function (coordinates) {
                var googleCoordinates = new   google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
                var pixelCoordinates =   overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(googleCoordinates);
                return [pixelCoordinates.x + 4000, pixelCoordinates.y +   4000];
            }


            var pointdata = pointjson.lat;
            console.log(pointdata);

            var positions = [];

            pointdata.forEach(function(d) {     
              positions.push(googleMapProjection(d.lat,d.lng)); 
            });


            var polygons = d3.geom.voronoi(positions);

            var pathAttr ={
                "d":function(d, i) { return "M" + polygons[i].join("L") + "Z"},
                stroke:"red",
                fill:"none"         
            };


            svgoverlay.selectAll("path")
            .data(pointdata)
            .attr(pathAttr)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "cell")
            .attr(pathAttr)

            var circleAttr = {
                "cx":function(d, i) { return positions[i][0]; },
                "cy":function(d, i) { return positions[i][1]; },
                "r":2,
                fill:"red"          
            }


            svgoverlay.selectAll("circle")
            .data(pointdata)
            .attr(circleAttr)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:circle")
            .attr(circleAttr)

        };

    };


    overlay.setMap(map);


};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The data file is of the structure:

```
[{"no":"10009","lat":"1.28210155945393","lng":"103.81722480263163",
  "name":"Bt Merah Int"},
 {"no":"10011","lat":"1.2777380589964","lng":"103.83749709165197",
  "name":"Opp New Bridge Rd Ter"}]
```

It is also giving an error in console:
TypeError: pointdata is undefined. I am trying to plot using the example: http://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/5610671
I am getting undefined for pointjson using console.log(). Please suggest how do I get the co-ordinate values in pointjson

Comment: Any help anyone...

Comment: I am getting undefined for pointjson using console.log(). Please suggest how do I get the co-ordinate values in pointjson.

Comment: The data structure used in the example you linked to is different to what you are trying to use. The example data structure is a JSON object which has a key called "features" (notice this bit: "features": [...])and the value of that key is an array of objects. Your data structure on the other hand is a simple array of objects. This is why you can not access the "lat" property the way you are trying to do it. In order to access this property you would have to iterate over your array. I suggest that you adjust your data structure to resemble the one used in the example.

Comment: Thanks Sir! I changed the data file to geojson format and it is working. Thank you